# Can I use a generic class parameter from the superclass of other generic class parameter as a method parameter

Tags: java

I have a hierarchy of generic classes and want to use the generic class parameter of my generic class parameter's superclass as a method parameter (i know it sounds confusing, please look at the code below)

```java
class Superclass<ID> { ... }

class MyClass<T extends Superclass<ID>, ID> { 

    T useId(ID id) { ... }

}
```

This above works, but I would love to get rid of the second generic class param (`ID`) since it's already in T somewhere. Is there a way to get and use the ID from the superclass as a method parameter?

Comment: Your code is confusing. `Superclass` is an interface, not a class, and `MyClass` doesn't extend or implement it. Please clarify your code.

Comment: And what do you think is the relationship between `ID` on `Superclass` and `ID` on `MyClass`?

Comment: @Eran that's right, MyClass doesn't extend or implement Superclass, but T does

Comment: @ernest_k it's the same thing, that's why I want to get rid of it

Answer (score 1):

Let's first change your code like this:

```
class MyClass<T extends Superclass<ID>, ID>
```

now you have the type safety that generics are designed for.
the ID in super is not the same in MyClass if you use "?" (Just placeholders with the same name). Now you don't want to get rid of the ID because that's the **compile-time safety** of your class.